# Data Structure for storing continuous time intervals and perform updates and deletes efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, intervals

I am in search for a data structure preferably in java for storing continuous time intervals and perform updates and deletes efficiently. 
These intervals can be grouped and while performing operations group will play a role.

Data looks like

```
 { [1, 3), [3, 5), [5, 8), [8, 10), [10, 12), [12, 15)... }  
First 3 intervals are Group1 and second 3 intervals are Group2 like continue...
```

Typical Operations on this data structure would be

- Add new interval with in group: [4, 6)

Result should be:

```
{ [1, 3), [3, 4), [4, 6), [6, 8), [8, 10), [10, 12), [12, 15)... }
* there is no change is Group 2.
```

- Add new interval through out: [4, 6)

Result: This should push into other groups too.

- Delete interval also can be performed with in group or through out all groups.

Like this any changes in these intervals should push or pull other intervals.
Please suggest me some efficient data structure for this.

Comment: kind of looks like a linked list to me

Comment: The question is not clear. The first operation - `Add new interval with in group: [4, 6)` - you meant adding this in the group 1? Then what does `Add new interval through out: [4, 6)` this mean? Can you please add more example? And what happens when you delete an interval? Can you delete multiple intervals at a time saying that `Delete [1,10)?

Comment: Add new interval with in group: [4, 6) - means adding only in that group. in this case group2 should not get affected. Add new interval through out: [4, 6) - means it could go into Group2 also.